# How to read and display all of the data inside a textfile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Currently I'm developing a word puzzle game and I'm having trouble of doing an endless mode of it. So what I am trying to do right now is I have a textfile(dictionary) that consists of thousands of words in it and I want to display each data one by one

for example : I have a button everytime I click it the first word will show up and if I click it again the 2nd word will show up something like

What I've tried so far is to display the first word on the textfile by doing something like this

```
TextAsset myTextAsset = Resources.Load("dictionary") as TextAsset;
string myString = myTextAsset.text;

Debug.Log(myString)
```

Could someone please help me figure out how to do it?

Comment: So what happens when you run your code?

Comment: @MickyD It can display the first word only on my text file

Comment: To show words, first you should seperate the whole text into words.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it .

```
public static List<string> textArray;

public Text textComp;

public int[] rowsToReadFrom;

public string FileName;

private TextAsset myTextAsset;
private void Start()
{
    myTextAsset = Resources.Load("dictionary") as TextAsset;
    string myString = myTextAsset.text;
}

public void readTextFile()
{
    textArray = myTextAsset.text.Split('\n').ToList();
    for(int i = 0; i < rowsToReadFrom.Length; i++)
    {
        if(rowsToReadFrom[0] < 0 || rowsToReadFrom.Length == 0)
        {
            textComp.text = myTextAsset.text;
        }
        else
        {
            textComp.text += textArray[rowsToReadFrom[i]] + "\n";
        }
    }

}
```

now my only problem is that increment every click but i guess i can handle it.

Comment: you should maybe clear your textfield once at the beginning of `readTextFile` in order to start with an empty text: `textComp.text = "";`